# What is a calibrated photodiode?

Tags: optics, laser, measurements

What is the difference between a calibrated photodiode and a not calibrated one?

Why to know a certain power value, for example for the P-I-V laser characterization, is it better to use a calibrated photodiode?

Answer (score 1):

A non-calibrated photodiode will give you just a voltage (or current) proportional to your laser power. A calibrated photodiode will tell you what that voltage corresponds to in terms of power. That is, the manufacturer has measured the voltage-to-power conversion ratio (for one or more wavelengths and/or gain settings, etc.) with some specified accuracy (and likely traceable to a NIST standard).

Get a calibrated detector for *absolute* laser power measurements (unless you feel comfortable calibrating it yourself); for *relative* measurements (where all you care about are proportional changes in power) a non-calibrated one will be fine.

Comment: Did you mean photodiode instead of laser diode?

Comment: @Ruslan haha, yes.