# Impact of photodiod's active area density on quantum efficiency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, experimental-physics, electronics

The quantum efficiency is a factor, telling me the ratio between optical input and electrical output. So I wondered, how does the efficiency depend on the density of the photodiod's active area? I mean the photon absorption probability is also dependent on the density of the material (+ the volume), isn't it?

How comes, that no photodiode shop provide information about the active area volume and density? Instead, they only inform about the active surface size?

Comment: They tell you the material it is made of (and hence the absorption coefficient) and often give you the dimensions and doping of the diode stack. So, for good diodes, the info is there in the reference material.

Comment: @JonCuster do you know a good photodiode with calibration curve (A/W) for wavelength around 670 nm and preferably under 50€?

Comment: @iwab, accurate calibration will depend on the optics of your system. Many vendors give a spectral response curve in A/W. For example, [here's one](https://osioptoelectronics.com/media/pages/products/photodetectors/photoconductive/osd1-0/69dd0ebb4a-1675100355/photoconductive-photodiodes.pdf) from OSI Optoelectronics.

Comment: @iwab - cheap _and_ calibrated? A real calibrated sensor will set you back perhaps 1500 (euros or dollars, close enough) (price picked at random from Newport). See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520322/what-is-a-calibrated-photodiode

Comment: @JonCuster I've found one (but in German language): https://www.reichelt.de/ir-fotodiode-s1337-66br-p217269.html?&trstct=pos_0&nbc=1 in the datasheet they also give a responsive curve in A/W and it only cost around 40€

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How comes, that no photodiode shop provide information about the active area volume and density?

Because that information isn't needed if they have told you the responsivity or the quantum efficiency, which they normally do.

> Instead, they only inform about the active surface size?

They give you this information so you know how small a spot you have to focus your input beam to in order to capture it (approximately) completely.

It is not related the quantum efficiency of the device, but it does affect the overall efficiency of the system if the beam is not small enough to be fully captured by the device.

Comment: So if I want to measure irradiance in mW/cm^2, it's enough to take the active area in cm^2 in the denominator?

Comment: @iwab, yes, assuming your beam is uniform in irradiance and you can align the photodiode surface perpendicular to the beam, and ...